# How can I share just the Product Backlog with a client using Team Foundation Service?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My team's project is hosted on the Team Foundation Service (TFS). How can I limit my client's access to the project to **only** the product backlog items?

The smallest set of rights seems to be 'View project-level information', but this still gives the user access to the code itself and I do not want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible today. We have heard that request more often, and it is tracked on [user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2085675-hide-work-item-types-wits-based-on-permission-se).

Feel free to vote for that suggestion. It helps us prioritize our work.

Answer (score 0):

To deny all access to code you need to:

- Open Source Control Explorer in VS2012
- Right click you Team Project's Name ($/MyTeamProject).
- Select "Advanced"
- Select "Security..."
- Select their TFS Group (i.e. Backlog Readers) on the Left Hand Side
- Click the "inherit allow" (or "allow") permission on the Right Hand Side until it changes to "deny".

Then save the changes.